# Angular 6 customPipe startDate endDate

Tags: angular

I'm new inangular front end, I want to make a custom pipe of data between two dates
my pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'customRangeFilter'
  })
  export class CustomRangeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items, from?:Date, to?:Date) {
      if(items && items.lenght){

        let startDate = new Date(from);
        let endDate = new Date(to);
        let a = items.filter(
          m => new Date(m.date) >= startDate && new Date(m.date) <= endDate
        )
        return a;

      }else{
        return items;
      }
    }
  }
```

in component.html

my other pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'customRangeFilter'
  })
  export class CustomRangeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

```
transform(items, from?:Date, to?:Date,) {
  if(items && items.lenght){

    let startDate = new Date(from);
    let endDate = new Date(to);
    let a = items.filter(
      m => new Date(m.date) >= startDate && new Date(m.date) <= endDate
    )
    return a;

  }else{
    return items;
  }
}
```

the customPipe what makes the comparison of the dates is not seen in the side  model

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I would like to have a filter between two given dates !! but it does not work so I wanted to know where the problem comes from !! Thank you